# I didn't recieve any items after level up, how do I get them?

Tags: pokemon-go

After levelling up past both level 11 and level 13 I didn't ever get the level up animation or any items for levelling up. I have checked my inventory and the items [listed on serebii.net](http://serebii.net/pokemongo/trainer.shtml) were definitely not added to my inventory. Dos anyone know how to get the items I should have?

I should also note that I'm now level 14 and so have levelled up past the levels at which the items didn't drop.

Comment: Sounds like a glitch where you lost out.. Try restarting the app before you level up (when you see the bar is close) and hopefully it won't make you miss out anymore

Comment: I've had it happen a couple times where I leveled up, it took about 5 minutes and me catching a couple more Pokemon before it actually triggered the 'Level Up' animation. I haven't seen it simply miss it entirely, though... that is unfortunate. :(

Comment: Did you get the reward for level 12?

Comment: @SPavel yes I did

Comment: Then you're probably not getting those items. At least the rewards for 11 and 13 aren't unique items...

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience (it happened last night), I leveled to 13, and it didn't give me my items. I had only 98 XP after evolving, so I hit a few Pokestops and on the 2nd one, I received the message about leveling up, and my items appeared.

I believe the solution is to just earn a bit more XP, and eventually the level up will appear.

Otherwise, rampant server issues have been noted since launch, and it's entirely possible that your reward did indeed get lost.

Comment: However I've already gotten a bit more exp, about 30000 to be exact